# Assigning values to multi-dimensional masked arrays does not clear the mask?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assigning to a masked array is supposed to clear the mask.  This works ok for me in a single-dimensional array, but doesn't work in a multi-dimensional array. I am able to workaround this by either flattening the array to a single dimension or assigning the mask explicitly (shown below), but it doesn't seem like I should have to do either of those.  Am I doing this wrong?

```
import numpy
marray = numpy.ma.masked_all(3)
marray
marray.hardmask
marray.data
marray.mask
marray[2] = 2
marray

marray2 = numpy.ma.masked_all((3,3))
marray2
marray2.hardmask
marray2.data
marray2.mask
marray2[2][2] = 2
marray2
marray2.data
marray2.mask
marray2.mask[2][2] = False
marray2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `marray2[2][2] = 2`, the first `[2]` is actually returning a *copy* of the 3rd row of the array, not a reference to the row within `marray2`, so you are manipulating the copy and not affecting `marray2`.

Unlike lists and tuples, numpy arrays support multidimensional indexing for multidimensional arrays. Try replacing `marray2[2][2] = 2` with `marray2[2,2] = 2` and I believe you will get the result you are expecting.

Comment: That did indeed work, but if I am manipulating a copy of marray2, how come I see my change in marray2.data after the assignment?  And how come adjusting the mask by hand then allows that data change to take affect?

Comment: Hm, interesting question. Maybe I was incorrect in that it's a copy, but that it just manipulates it differently depending on the indexing type? Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow (posting). I've un-accepted your answer in the hopes that an unanswered question will attract more eyeballs.  Is that appropriate?  If yours ends up still being the best answer in a few days, I'll re-accept it.